# How to find the standard deviation of alternative cells in excel 2007

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I want to calculate the standard deviation of alternative cells in a 10000 rows in excel 2007, how can i do that ? whether i need a formula or a VBA ?. Can some help me.

Comment: So i think i need a VBA for doing this ? Can some one help me with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use both, the following code splits/sorts your rows and selects every second row and pastes it into another column, beginning with the first cell:

```
Sub splitcells()

Dim rows As Long

Dim i, j As Long

j = 0

rows = ?1?

For i = ?2? To rows Step 2

    Cells(i - j, ?4?).Value = Cells(i, ?3?).Value

    j = j + 1

Next

End Sub
```

Then you have to replace:

?1? - with the end row number of your list

?2? - with the beginning row number of your list

?3? - the column number of your list to be sorted

?4? - the column number of your destination column (the one the sorted data is sent to)

Once you have completed this, just run a normal standard deviation function on your new column and you'll have your answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, its working.. So much of my time is saved.

Answer (score 3):

It's also possible with a formula. This "array formula" gives you standard deviation of every other cell starting at A1

`=STDEV(IF(MOD(ROW(A1:A10000)-ROW(A1),2)=0,A1:A10000))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>